# Aftermath of melting ice

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, phase-transition, equilibrium, ice

This is a familiar question but I have something different to ask . What will be the aftermath when ice melts

- what will happen to the interface of water and oil will it rise or fall
- what will happen to the level of liquid as a whole will the level drop

I really dont know whether this question suits this site
[image] $d_{rel.oil}$=0.8
$d_{rel.ice}$=0.9

Comment: Archimedes to the rescue!

Comment: Chemistry trivia:  Pure water, with all dissolved gases removed, will readily mix with oil.  It's only "normal" water, full of dissolved atmosphere, that refuses to mix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the ice is in equilibrium in between the oil and water it receives upthrust from both the liquids thus it is not displacing its own weight in the water anymore(displaces less). When the ice melts the water will actually rise and the absence of the ice cube in oil will cause the level of oil to sink.

For the overall effect, since ice is less dense than water when it melts the same mass of ice will occupy a lesser volume. It occupies more volume in its unmelted form so if it melts the overall level will reduce.

Comment: Talking about the interface , I got it intuitively does this work for every situation, or is there a mathematical way to show

Comment: It will always be the case for water as its solid form is less dense than its liquid form. For a mathematical way to show it: $$V_{ice}=\frac{m}{\rho _{ice}},V_{water}=\frac{m}{\rho _{water}}$$
As $$\rho_{ice}<\rho_{water}$$ Final volume of the system decreases

Answer (score 0):

- In short: Water level will remain same and oil level will come down.

Explanation:

- Ice density is less than water so it floats but is displaces the amount of water equal to its weight. As there is no change in weight of ice-water system before and after melting, there will be no change in the water level.
- Less denser ice converts to denser water so overall volume of ice-water system reduces.
- Since water and ice both are denser than oil they will sink and oil will float over them. Once the ice melts, whatever oil the less denser floating cube of ice is displacing (the protruding portion of ice out of water) will bring the oil level down.